# Cannot run supervisor in Docker as a non-root user

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, supervisord

I've got a containerized app using `docker-compose` to bundle up the backend, the frontend, the database and nginx. Now, I need to add `supervisor` but I'm getting some errors while running `docker-compose`:

> dmc-app    | Error: Can't drop privilege as nonroot user

I think I know where the error is coming from but I don't know how to fix it.

Let me first show you my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:8.1.12-fpm

ARG uid=1000
ARG user=inigomontoya

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    git \
    curl \
    zip \
    unzip \
    supervisor

# Install and enable xDebug
RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install php modules required by laravel.
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd zip

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan commands.
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

# Install composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create directory for supervisor logs
RUN mkdir -p "/etc/supervisor/logs" && chmod -R 775 "/etc/supervisor/logs"

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

USER $user


# Copy supervisor config files
COPY ./docker/config/supervisor/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

and here's my `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: dmc
    container_name: dmc-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/
    depends_on:
      - db
      - nginx
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/
      - ./docker/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
      - ./docker/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini
      - ./images:/public/images
    expose:
      - "9003"
    networks:
      - dmc-net

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23.2-alpine
    container_name: dmc-nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker-compose/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - dmc-net

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.31
    container_name: dmc-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    # using 3307 on the host machine to avoid collisions in case there's a local MySQL instance installed already.
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    # use the variables declared in .env file
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: abcd1234
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./docker-compose/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - dmc-net

  dmc-web:
    build:
      context: /Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-ui
      dockerfile: /Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-ui/Dockerfile
      target: dev
    container_name: dmc-web
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1313:3000"
      - "5137:5137"
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      # it avoids mounting the workspace root
      # because it may cause OS specific node_modules folder
      # or build folder(.svelte-kit) to be mounted.
      # they conflict with the temporary results from docker space.
      # this is why many mono repos utilize ./src folder
      - /Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-ui/src:/app/src
      - /Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-ui/static:/app/app/static
      - /Users/hansgruber/Desktop/webdev/projects/dundermifflin-ui/static:/app/static/
    depends_on:
      - app
      - nginx
      - db
    links:
      - app
    networks:
      - dmc-net

networks:
  dmc-net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

here's my `supervisord.conf`:

```
[supervisord]
user=root
logfile=/etc/supervisor/logs/supervisord.log ; main log file; default $CWD/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes=5MB         ; max main logfile bytes b4 rotation; default 50MB
logfile_backups=10           ; # of main logfile backups; 0 means none, default 10
loglevel=info                ; log level; default info; others: debug,warn,trace
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; supervisord pidfile; default supervisord.pid
nodaemon=true                ; start in foreground if true; default false
minfds=1024                  ; min. avail startup file descriptors; default 1024
minprocs=200                 ; min. avail process descriptors;default 200
loglevel = INFO

[program:app-worker]
user=root
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/app/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/storage/logs/worker.log
```

as you can see in my `Dockerfile` I've created an user:

```
ARG user=inigomontoya
...
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
```

and then by the end of the file I'm setting this user:

```
USER $user
```

But as far as I understand `supervisor` needs to be run by `root`.

Here's what I've tried so far:

**Attempt 1**

I tried replacing `user=root` by `user=inigomontoya` in `supervisord.conf` which is the user I've created in my `Dockerfile` but I'm still getting the following error over and over again:

```
dmc-app    | 2024-01-27 05:48:40,690 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf" during parsing
dmc-app    | 2024-01-27 05:48:40,690 INFO Set uid to user 1000 succeeded
dmc-app    | Error: Cannot open an HTTP server: socket.error reported errno.EACCES (13)
dmc-app    | For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
```

**Attempt 2**

Attempted to create a new section in the `Dockerfile` where I used an `alpine` image and installed `supervisor` in it. Then added a new service to my `docker-compose` file:

```
  supervisor:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: supervisor
    image: dmc
    container_name: dmc-supervisor
    networks:
      - dmc-net
    depends_on:
      - app
      - nginx
    command:
      - supervisord
```

didn't work obviously since it's a separate container and don't have access to php, and as you can see the command executed in supervisor is `command=php /var/www/app/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3`

**Attempt 3**

Switching user to `root` in `Dockerfile` right before creating the supervisor logs directory, copying the supervisor files and running CMD:

```
...

# Install composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

USER root

# Create directory for supervisor logs
RUN mkdir -p "/etc/supervisor/logs" && chmod -R 775 "/etc/supervisor/logs"

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Copy supervisor config files
COPY ./docker/config/supervisor/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

This has caused two issues.

1. I believe `supervisor` has started correctly, I don't see any errors in the output related specifically to `supervisor` but I do see errors related to one of the programs defined in the conf file `[program:app-worker]`:

```
dmc-app    | 2024-01-27 06:02:47,589 INFO spawned: 'app-worker_00' with pid 8
dmc-app    | 2024-01-27 06:02:47,605 INFO exited: app-worker_00 (exit status 1; not expected)
dmc-app    | 2024-01-27 06:02:49,608 INFO spawned: 'app-worker_00' with pid 9
dmc-app    | 2024-01-27 06:02:49,621 INFO exited: app-worker_00 (exit status 1; not expected)
dmc-app    | 2024-01-27 06:02:52,629 INFO spawned: 'app-worker_00' with pid 10
dmc-app    | 2024-01-27 06:02:52,642 INFO exited: app-worker_00 (exit status 1; not expected)
dmc-app    | 2024-01-27 06:02:53,644 INFO gave up: app-worker_00 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

2. I believe the app is running now as `root` instead of the user created initially (`inigomontoya`) so my app UI loads but now it cannot connect to the backend:

```
dmc-nginx  | 2024/01/27 06:05:35 [error] 21#21: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.65.1, server: dmc-server, request: "GET /api/products?page=1 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://192.168.80.4:9000", host: "host.docker.internal:8000"
dmc-nginx  | 192.168.65.1 - - [27/Jan/2024:06:05:35 +0000] "GET /api/products?page=1 HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "undici"
dmc-web    | SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<html>
dmc-web    | <h"... is not valid JSON
dmc-web    |     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
dmc-web    |     at parseJSONFromBytes (/app/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/body.js:579:15)
dmc-web    |     at successSteps (/app/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/body.js:519:23)
dmc-web    |     at fullyReadBody (/app/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/util.js:863:5)
dmc-web    |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
dmc-web    |     at async specConsumeBody (/app/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/body.js:534:3)
dmc-web    |     at async ProductAPI.fetchData (/app/src/lib/api/api.js:162:16)
dmc-web    |     at async load (/app/src/routes/products/+page.server.js:8:22)
dmc-web    |     at async Module.load_server_data (/app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/page/load_data.js:51:17)
dmc-web    |     at async Promise.all (index 1)
```

So the user created in the `Dockerfile` is needed for the app to work correctly.

**Questions**

- My main question at this point is: is there a way to use my custom user to run the app and `root` to run `supervisor`?
- So I've read that each docker container should have 1 process, the way I'm trying to solve this is having 2 processes in one container, the one that's basically running the laravel app (backend), is that right? As I mentioned before, I tried to create a separate container to run only `supervisor`, but couldn't get it to work since all the files and the executable live on a different container.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run multiple containers off the same image.  That's usually a better practice than trying to setup supervisord, especially if you have Compose already and especially if you're having trouble getting supervisord to run.

If you're building the image locally, specify the same `build:` block in both containers, but override the `command:` in one of them (or both).  Compose will do the image-build process twice, and `docker images` will list two images, but they will be physically the same image (they'll have the same image hash) and the second build will come entirely from cache.

So you can delete all of the supervisord setup in your Dockerfile, and keep your existing non-root user.  Your Compose file might look like (simplifying `build:` and removing several unnecessary options):

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - db

  worker:
    build: .
    command: /var/www/app/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Of the options I've deleted, it's possible you'll need to keep `volumes:` in both containers, but in normal use the application code should already get `COPY`ed into the image.  I've deleted `networks:` here, and this needs to be done consistently through the entire file – delete all of the `networks:` blocks everywhere.

Comment: Hi David. I've tried adding the worker but when running it I'm getting the following error: `/usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint: 9: exec: /var/www/app/artisan: not found`. One other question I have is: why `networks` property needs to be removed from the file? I thought we needed to specify a network all the containers will use to communicate with each other

Comment: Compose provides a network named `default` for you, and attaches containers to it if they don't have any other `networks:` declaration.  In normal use you should not need to set `networks:` or `container_name:`; inter-container networking will still work fine.

Comment: Scanning through the Dockerfile, are you maybe missing the `COPY` line that copies the application code into the image?

Comment: yes, I don't have a `COPY` command in my `Dockerfile` to copy the app code into the image, but I'm mounting the following volume `./:/var/www/` in my `docker-compose` file, ain't those equivalent?

Comment: Ok, I figured out what is going on. Basically when copying over the files `composer` ends up living in `/var/www/` which will basically be the root of my project, and the command listed is pointing to `/var/www/app/artisan` which is incorrect, it should be `/var/www/artisan`. Thanks for your help. I believe this approach of having a separate container for `supervisor` is much better